# Given the following recurrence relation $ x_{n+1} = 1 − \sqrt{1 − x_n}$, does$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ converge or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that a sequence $ x_n $ in $\mathbb R$ satisfies reccurence relation
$$ x_{n+1} = 1 − \sqrt{1 − x_n}$$
Does $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ converge or not?

---

I have found that the limit of $x_{n+1}=1-\sqrt{1-x_n}$ is $0$ for all $x_1<1$. I cannot figure out the limit of $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ since at those values it becomes $\frac{0}{0}$ form.

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say what your thoughts on it are, and what you have tried to solve the problem; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, please try to make the title more descriptive, there are a lot of questions about convergence of recurrence relations.

Comment: i have found the limits of $$ x_{n+1} = 1 − \sqrt{1 − x_n} $$ is 0  for all $$ x_{1}  $$values less than 1

Comment: If $x_1 > 1$ then $x_2 = 1 - \sqrt{1-x_1}$ is undefined, so you don't need to concern yourself with $x_1 > 1$

Comment: If $x_1 = 1$, then $x_2 = 1 - \sqrt{1-1} = 1$, so $x_n = 1 \forall n$. And so $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = 1$

Comment: but if the value is less than 1 then where  $$ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} $$ converges

Comment: After trying some values, it seems like the answer is $0$ for $\left| x_0 \right| < 1$

Comment: As $x$ tends to 0, $1-\sqrt{1-x}\approx{x\over2}$, so I guess the answer must be: yes, the ratio converges to $1\over2$.

Comment: yes thats true but i cant figure out the limit of $$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$$ AT THOSE VLUES AS IT BECOMES $$\frac{0}{0}$$ FORM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out, $0<x_0<1$ implies $x_n\to 0$. Then with the substitution $y=\sqrt{1-x}$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{x}=\lim_{y\to 1^-}\frac{1-y}{1-y^2}=\lim_{y\to 1^-}\frac{1-y}{(1-y)(1+y)}=\frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, $x_1>1$ is ignored.

If $x_1 = 1$, then $x_2 = 1 - \sqrt{1-1} = 1 \implies  x_n = 1$ and so , $$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = 1$$

If  $x_1<1$ then $x_n \to 0$ and we can write $x_{n+1} = 1-\sqrt{1-x_n}$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \lim_{x_n \to 0 } \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x_n}}{x_n}$$

Can you solve this limit?

Comment: You can use the [binomial theorem for fractional powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) to solve the last limit in case you don't know how to.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another technique which is helpful if you have a limit involving variables tending to zero is to analyze the series expansion of the involved functions. Note that

\begin{equation}
  \sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^2)
\end{equation}

for $x \to 0$. Thus:

\begin{equation}
  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x}}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - (1 - \frac{x}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^2))}{x} = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}